# Issue with Button Functionality: Clickable but Not Inserting Data into Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to create a check-in and check-out page using Flutter. The page should have two buttons for check-in and check-out. The check-in button is working correctly, and the timestamp is successfully inserted into Firebase. However, the check-out button is not functioning as expected.

This is the code.

```
class _CheckInOutState extends State<CheckInOut> {
  DateTime? checkInTime;
  DateTime? checkOutTime;
  bool isCheckedIn = false;

  String getFormattedDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
    return DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(dateTime);
  }

  Future<void> saveCheckInOutTime() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('checkInOut').add({
        'fileName': widget.selectedFileName,
        'checkInTime': isCheckedIn ? Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()) : null,
        'checkOutTime': !isCheckedIn ? Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()) : null,
        'staffName': widget.staffName,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error saving check-in/out time: $e');
    }
  }

   void toggleCheckInOut() async {
    setState(() {
      isCheckedIn = !isCheckedIn;
      if (isCheckedIn) {
        // Check In
        checkInTime = DateTime.now();
        checkOutTime = null; // Reset checkOutTime when checking in
      } else {
        // Check Out
        checkOutTime = DateTime.now();
      }
    });

    // Save check-in and check-out times to Firestore
    await saveCheckInOutTime();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Check In/Out'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            if (isCheckedIn && checkInTime != null)
              Text(
                'Check In: ${getFormattedDateTime(checkInTime!)}',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
            if (!isCheckedIn && checkOutTime != null)
              Text(
                'Check Out: ${getFormattedDateTime(checkOutTime!)}',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: isCheckedIn ? null : toggleCheckInOut,
              child: Text(isCheckedIn ? 'Checked In' : 'Check In'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: isCheckedIn ? toggleCheckInOut : null,
              child: Text(isCheckedIn ? 'Check Out' : 'Checked Out'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have been trying to search on the internet, but I have hit a dead end. There are no errors in the code. Both buttons can clickable. Please help me with this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have successfully solved this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permission to write?

Rules

```
match /checkInOut/{ID} {
   allow read, write: if true;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to put 'if true'? because my Firebase rules only have 'allow read, write'

Comment: And the button for check-in can function correctly, but not the button for check-out. So, it may not be a problem with the rules.

Comment: I have run your code!

Comment: At first, it throw an error for permission to write, After I updated the Rules its works.

Comment: W/Firestore(15095): (24.1.2) [WriteStream]: (517f455) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.
W/Firestore(15095): (24.1.2) [Firestore]: Write failed at checkInOut/4POKjzuDWMmDO0I27FJE: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
I/flutter (15095): Error saving check-in/out time: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

Comment: I have tried, but it's not working, sir. It shows null for checkOutTime.

Comment: I/flutter (15095): After write DOC ID : OrZY4nBaJIMiinIbMZ5b

Comment: On checked in {fileName: widget.selectedFileName, checkOutTime: null, checkInTime: Timestamp(seconds=1690015929, nanoseconds=185073000), staffName: widget.staffName}

Comment: {fileName: widget.selectedFileName, checkOutTime: Timestamp(seconds=1690016085, nanoseconds=564000000), checkInTime: null, staffName: widget.staffName}

Comment: Can you please explain to me what you are trying to do?

Comment: "What I want to do is to let the user choose the filename, and after the user clicks the filename, the check in and check out page will appear. The code above is intended for users to check in when they take a hardcopy file and check out after use. So, from list filename page to check in and check out page.

Comment: Do you want an update to the existing doc?

Comment: Do you mean at check-in time? I am considering having both check-in and check-out.